# Two cars are moving away from each other. what is the frequency heard by observer in one of the car if the other blows a horn?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, kinematics, doppler-effect

The cars are moving with same velocity in the opposite direction (one going south and the other is going north)

Comment: What are the speeds of the automobiles?

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) and [edit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/612374/edit) your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the following relation

$$f=\frac{v-v_{car}}{v+v_{car}}f_0$$

where $v$ is the velocity of the medium and $v_{car}$ is the velocity of the cars since both cars have the same velocity. $f$ is the frequency heard by the other car.